Sharepoint (OneDrive) Upload file to subfolder using .NET Framework 4.8 c#
I'm trying to upload a simple text file into my Sharepoint/OneDrive subfolder (I am a contractor and perform web development for the FAA so the Sharepoint site is on the secured FAA network) at the following URL:
https://usfaa-my.sharepoint.com/personal/james_k-ctr_beaumont_faa_gov/Documents/ACOCMS/SysData
I'm using the following NuGet packages:
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Online.CSOM
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
SharePoint.Client.Office.Tools

Here is my code:
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

string SiteUrl = "https://usfaa-my.sharepoint.com/";
string DocumentLibrary = "personal";
string FileName = "D:\Work\repos\Part16CMS\App_Data\ErrorLogDC.txt";
string CustomerFolder = "SysData";
string UserName = "[My Email Address]@faa.gov";
string Password = "**********";

UploadFileToSharePoint(SiteUrl, DocumentLibrary, CustomerFolder, FileName, UserName, Password);

private static void UploadFileToSharePoint(string SiteUrl, string DocLibrary, string ClientSubFolder, string FileName, string Login, string Password)
{
    try
    {
        #region ConnectToSharePoint

        var securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in Password)
        { securePassword.AppendChar(c); }
        var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Login, securePassword);
        #endregion

        #region Insert the data
        using (ClientContext CContext = new ClientContext(SiteUrl))
        {
            CContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
            Web web = CContext.Web;
            FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
            byte[] FileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);
            newFile.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(FileContent);
            newFile.Url = Path.GetFileName(FileName);
            List DocumentLibrary = web.Lists.GetByTitle(DocLibrary);
            Folder Clientfolder = DocumentLibrary.RootFolder.Folders.Add(ClientSubFolder);
            Clientfolder.Update();
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = Clientfolder.Files.Add(newFile);

            CContext.Load(DocumentLibrary);
            CContext.Load(uploadFile);
            CContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }

        #endregion
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exp.Message + Environment.NewLine + exp.StackTrace);
    }
}

I'm pretty close, at least I think I am. The code runs until I get to CContext.ExecuteQuery(); at which point I get the following error:
"List 'personal' does not exist at site with URL 'https://usfaa-my.sharepoint.com'."
I'm not sure if the credentials are even being accepted or authenticated though nothing throws an error until I get to CContext.ExecuteQuery();
I can't figure out what the DocumentLibrary variable should be set to and can't seem to determine what the document library title actually is. I'm also not sure if the CustomerFolder variable is correct.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Microsoft documentation on all of this is far from clear or detailed enough, IMHO. Thanks!

Try to change the site url to "https://usfaa-my.sharepoint.com/personal/james_k-ctr_beaumont_faa_gov" since "personal" is the managed path and "james_k-ctr_beaumont_faa_gov" is the site name. So the library is "documents".

Awesome, that did it! Is there a way to upload a file to a subfolder within documents? I tried changing the CustomerFolder variable to "ACOCMS\LogData" and @"ACOCMS/LogData" and both result in the error "Access is denied". No big deal as I just created a folder right under "documents" named "ACOCMS-Logdata" but would like to know if there is a way to upload a file to a subfolder.

Well you have to check if the folder exists. So you have to split your CustomerFolder by the slash, create the first folder (if not exists), then the second one inside the first one (if not exists) and so on.
